# Does ballerina have support for sorting?

Tags: ballerina

It is required to sort some array of ballerina objects based on the private variable value. Can we sort ballerina object or primitive type array ? Is there any function to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `array:sort` function available in Ballerina.

```
int[] arr = [5,4,3,2,1];
int[] sorted = arr.sort();
```

Refer to https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/0.0.0/functions#sort for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no inbuilt way you can sort an array. You can implement a sort function as per your need.

Found an implementation in github which you could reuse - https://github.com/chamil321/ballerinaCentralWorkSpace/blob/master/sort/impl.bal. But its for integers. I think it refers to https://central.ballerina.io/chamil/sort package. You can pull the package and try it out.

Comment: `int[] unsortedArray = [10, 15, 2, 5, 3, 0]; int[] result = sort:mergeSort(unsortedArray);` https://github.com/chamil321/ballerinaCentralWorkSpace/blob/master/sort/Package.md

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ballerina does now support sorting, but you have to do all the heavy lifting. Even for simple value types. Alas.

Anyway, here's a stab at a "sort in alphabetical order" for an array which has json elements each with a name element - obvs would also work for simple ints or strings or worreva with some tweaking:

```
json items = [{ name: "aaa" }, { name: "aab" }];
items.sort(sortItems)

function sortItems(json a, json b) returns int {
    // extract character by character numeric representation of string
    int[] aname = a.name.toString().toCodePointInts();
    int[] bname = b.name.toString().toCodePointInts();

    // do character by character comparison
    int i = 0;
    while (i < aname.length() && i < bname.length()) {
        if (aname[i] < bname[i]) { return -1; }
        else if (aname[i] > bname[i]) { return 1; }
        i += 1;
    }
    // if all the characters in the shared length is the same
    // assume the shorter string should come first
    if (aname.length() < bname.length()) { return -1; }
    if (aname.length() > bname.length()) { return 1; }

    return 0;
}
```

Happy to be corrected and for there to be a simpler native way to do this. (The array initialisation might be wrong, not tested that bit, soz.)

Comment: You can use language integrated queries as below. Atm, it requires converting the json to a user defined record collection to be sorted.

```
import ballerina/io;
type DummyRec record {|
    string name;
|};


json items = [{ name: "aac" }, { name: "aab" }, { name: "aaa" }];

public function main() returns error? {
    DummyRec[] arr = check items.cloneWithType();
    DummyRec[] sortedArr = from DummyRec item in arr
    order by item.name
    select item;
    
    io:println(sortedArr);

    json sortedJson = sortedArr.toJson();
    io:println(sortedJson);

}
```

Comment: Sample is written on Ballerina 2201.0.3